# Valid way to show that the origin is the only critical point?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, dynamical-systems

> I am trying to show that the origin is the only critical point of $$x'=y+kx(x^2+y^2), \ \ y'=-x+ky(x^2+y^2) \ \ \  \ k\in\mathbb{R}.$$

If we re-write in polar coordinates, we can show that $$r'=kr^3.$$
Then $r'=0$ is only satisfied when $r=0\implies x=y=0\implies x'=y'=0$.

The answer in my textbook used a much more rigorous algebraic proof (i.e. manipulate both $x'$ and $y'$ equations to find that $x=y=0$ is the only solution which satisfies $x'=y'=0$). Is my method legitimate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your method is correct.

$$x'=y+kx(x^2+y^2), \ \ y'=-x+ky(x^2+y^2) \ \ \  \ k\in\mathbb{R}.$$

Note that $$rr'= xx'+yy'$$

$$rr'= xy+kx^2(x^2+y^2)-xy+ky^2(x^2+y^2)=k(x^2+y^2)^2$$

which does imply to $$r'=kr^3$$

The origin is the only equilibrium.

Comment: My sincerest apologies. The equation should read $y'=-x+ky(x^2+y^2)$. I have corrected this.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Showing that at any equilibrium $r=0$ does not immediately imply that $x=y=0$, namely if $x=1$ and $y=i$ would also yield $r=0$. However when $r=0$ yields $x'=y$ and $y'=-x$, from which only the origin as equilibrium follows. Also one has to cover the case when $k=0$, because that is not covered by your argument.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Are you able to post your working? I'm not sure I completely understand what you mean.

Comment: @sjmb $r=0$ only implies $x=y=0$ if $x$ and $y$ are real. But you only stated that $k$ should be real, so I assumed that $x$ and $y$ could be complex. Further more I am assuming that $r$ is still defined as $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, which can be zero even though $x$ and $y$ are not zero.